# MaxMind's GeoIP database

Tags: geoip

I found that the MaxMind's GeoIP database's accuracy is 99.5% (free) or 99.8% (commercial), as published in their website. Does anybody know what would be the 0.5% and the 0.2% ?

Are they newly assigned IP addresses, or actual addresses that change their countries?

I feel that my question is not very clear but any answers are welcome.

Answer (score 9):

A bit late, but the [MaxMindGeoIP Country](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geoip_country) page spells this out a bit.

Basically the paid version corrects for AOL, and "some" anonymous proxies / satellite providers.

I get the sense that AOL is the biggest issue. For the free version, all AOL users show up in the US, while the paid version correctly identifies AOL users in Great Britain, France, Germany, and Brazil. I don't know how many people use AOL in Europe these days, so I'm not sure how big of an issue this is.

Regarding what "some" means regarding the anonymous proxies or satellite providers, I have no idea.